# How to add swipe/drag view from bottom in windows 8.1 phone

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

Hey I want to do in my windows 8.1 phone app a View that I can swipe from the bottom of the window (Images below explain it better).  The view must allow to swipe/drag it to the bottom again. Any idea or tip of how can I do that? Thank you in advance.

This is what I want to have initially
[image: Image - Initial state of view]

[image: Image - On swiping of view]

Comment: Why don't you just use an appbar?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Windows phone **Bottom App Bar**.This will give you the desired functionality.But you **Cannot Customize** the bottom app bar e.g. you cannot add the radio button or checkbox to it.It has its own predefined buttons called as **AppBarButton** & **AppBarToggleButtons**.
For more information you can visit the following link :
[Windows Phone 8.1 for Developers – Application bar](http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/09/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-application-bar/)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: whether we able to swipe up this view to full page ? I need some thing like that we see in android, drag up view. Is it possible in windows phone ?

Comment: Possibly not because Application Bar can not be swipe up to full page although you can swipe up to half of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
MainPage.xaml

```
<Page x:Name="page"
x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Canvas Background="Red">
    <Grid>
        <!--Your layout-->
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="swipingContent"  Canvas.Left="0"  Background="Black" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=page, Mode=OneWay}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Thumb x:Name="thumb" Height="35" ManipulationMode="TranslateY" IsEnabled="True" ManipulationDelta="Thumb_ManipulationDelta"/>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Text="Heading" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" IsChecked="True" Content="Some CheckBox"/>
        <!--and other layout-->
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().HideAsync();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        this.SizeChanged += MainPage_SizeChanged;

    }

    private void MainPage_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        swipingContent.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, e.NewSize.Height - thumb.ActualHeight);
    }


    private void Thumb_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var maxSwipedHeight = swipingContent.Height;
        var currentPosition = (double)swipingContent.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);
        var distanceFromBottom = this.ActualHeight - currentPosition;
        var targetDistance = distanceFromBottom  - e.Delta.Translation.Y;
        double targetPosition;
        if (targetDistance <= thumb.ActualHeight)
        {
            targetPosition = this.ActualHeight - thumb.ActualHeight;
        }
        else if (targetDistance >= maxSwipedHeight)
        {
            targetPosition = this.ActualHeight - maxSwipedHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            targetPosition = this.ActualHeight - targetDistance;
        }
        swipingContent.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, targetPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But in given solution swipe content up is not smooth,     not swiping up corresponding to velocity of swipe. I need something like windows top notification bar like animated swipe up view. Please help.